# Is it possible to transpose rows to columns in C#.net and listing data?

Tags: c#, sql

I have list of two different items like Employees and Departments, both having many to many relations.

Employees:

```
EmpID     EmpName
1          emp1
2          emp2
3          emp3
```

Departments:

```
DeptID   DeptName  
1        dept1       
2        dept2       
3        dept3
```

```
Relation Table
relationID empID  DeptID
1           1       1
2           1       2
3           2       3
4           3       1
5           3       3
```

And my requirements: and department are not fixed

```
empID  Name           Dept1     Dept2   Dept3
1      emp1           yes       yes     No
2      emp2           no        no      yes   
3      emp3           yes       no      yes
```

Is it possible to do, if yes please light me thanks.

```
Json data will be, emplist: [{"empID": "1", "name": "emp1", "Dept1": "yes", "dept2": "yes", "Dept3": "yes"}, {"empID": "2", "name": "emp2", "Dept1": "no", "dept2": "no", "Dept3": "yes"}, {"empID": "3", "name": "emp3", "Dept1": "yes", "dept2": "no", "Dept3": "yes"}];
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You need a sql to output data in tabular format?

Comment: Hey Utsav, let say I have list of employee and list of department w.r.t to employee I want those two list to be in one list as parent list  and the departments list to be as a row in parent. Is it possible to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this linq

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;


namespace ConsoleApplication58
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DataTable employeesTable = new DataTable();
            employeesTable.Columns.Add("EmpID", typeof(int));
            employeesTable.Columns.Add("EmpName", typeof(string));
            employeesTable.Rows.Add(new object[] {1, "emp1"});
            employeesTable.Rows.Add(new object[] {2, "emp2"});
            employeesTable.Rows.Add(new object[] {3, "emp3"});

            DataTable departmentTable = new DataTable();
            departmentTable.Columns.Add("DeptID", typeof(int));
            departmentTable.Columns.Add("DeptName", typeof(string));
            departmentTable.Rows.Add(new object[] {1, "dept1"});
            departmentTable.Rows.Add(new object[] {2, "dept2"});
            departmentTable.Rows.Add(new object[] {3, "dept3"});


            DataTable relationTable = new DataTable();
            relationTable.Columns.Add("RelationID", typeof(int));
            relationTable.Columns.Add("EmpID", typeof(int));
            relationTable.Columns.Add("DeptID", typeof(int));
            relationTable.Rows.Add(new object[] {1, 1, 1});
            relationTable.Rows.Add(new object[] {2, 1, 2});
            relationTable.Rows.Add(new object[] {3, 2, 3});
            relationTable.Rows.Add(new object[] {4, 3, 1});
            relationTable.Rows.Add(new object[] {5, 3, 3});

            var joinTables =
               (from r in relationTable.AsEnumerable()
               join e in employeesTable.AsEnumerable() on r.Field<int>("EmpID") equals e.Field<int>("EmpID")
               join d in departmentTable.AsEnumerable() on r.Field<int>("DeptID") equals d.Field<int>("DeptID")
               select new { 
                   relationID = r.Field<int>("RelationID"), 
                   employeeID = e.Field<int>("EmpID"),
                   employeeName = e.Field<string>("EmpName"),
                   department = d.Field<string>("DeptName")
               })
               .ToList();

            var results = joinTables.GroupBy(x => x.employeeID).Select(y => new {
               employee = new {
                   empID = y.FirstOrDefault().employeeID,
                   empName = y.FirstOrDefault().employeeName,
                   Dept1 = y.Where(z => z.department == "dept1").Any() ? "yes" : "no",
                   Dept2 = y.Where(z => z.department == "dept2").Any() ? "yes" : "no",
                   Dept3 = y.Where(z => z.department == "dept3").Any() ? "yes" : "no"
               }
            }).ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

If you have a large list of departments you can do this instead

```
            List<string> departments = departmentTable.AsEnumerable().Select(x => x.Field<string>("DeptName")).Distinct().OrderBy(y => y).ToList();

            var results = joinTables.GroupBy(x => x.employeeID).Select(y => new {
               employee = new {
                   empID = y.FirstOrDefault().employeeID,
                   empName = y.FirstOrDefault().employeeName,
                   departments = departments.Select(d => y.Where(z => z.department == d).Any() ? d + ": yes" : d + ": no").ToList()
                }
            }).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks jdweng for the answer :), I have approached in different way, though the answer is coming correct. so accepted as answered.